# subsytems of second order arithmetic

Tags: arithmetic, second-order-logic

Consider the 5 prominent subsystems of second order arithmetic.
I would like to know which of these subsystems of second order arithmetic have computably axiomatizable theory.

Comment: Each of the "Big Five" - that is, $\mathsf{RCA_0},\mathsf{WKL_0},\mathsf{ACA_0},\mathsf{ATR_0},$ and $\Pi^1_1$-$\mathsf{CA_0}$ - is obviously computably axiomatized; just look at how they're defined! In fact, each is *finitely axiomatizable*, although this is less obvious.

Comment: @NoahSchweber OK. Is there a natural theory which is not recursive/finitely axiomatizable ?

Comment: True arithmetic is of course not recursively, or even arithmetically, axiomatizable. Peano arithmetic $\mathsf{PA}$ is recursively axiomatizable but not finitely axiomatizable; note that $\mathsf{ACA_0}$ is a conservative extension of $\mathsf{PA}$, so non-finite-axiomatizability is less "inherent" than one might expect. A similar phenomenon occurs with respect to $\mathsf{ZFC}$ versus $\mathsf{NBG}$ (see also [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/326470/does-every-first-order-theory-have-a-finitely-axiomatizable-conservative-exten)).